# Pass the forms data from view to controller and save to database in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, view, controller, html.beginform

I have a table in my database and it has a column named title in `nvarchar` datatype. I want to save the title that user enters in a textbox to table. In my view I used

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("savetodb", "Advertise", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AdTitle)
}
```

This view is strongly typed view from a ViewModel that has this property

```
public string AdTitle { get; set; }
```

I know how to save data from controller to database but I don't know how can I access data in my controller(in `savetodb()` function). Can anybody help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public ActionResult SaveToDB(YourViewModel model)
{
    // Do what you want with AdTitle here.
    SaveInDB(model.AdTitle);
}
```

Comment: it would have been more useful if I could actually see which fires the SaveToDB method :(

Answer (score 1):

View Model coud be one way but in this case i think it`s better to use auto model binding of MVC 3.so if u define a string parameter with the name of AdTitle.

```
 public ActionResult SaveToDB(String AdTitle)
{
    // Do what you want with AdTitle here.
    SaveInDB(AdTitle);
}
```

Comment: ummm... That code looks familiar. Where did I see it before...? I'm sure I did see it but where?